# How to load more than one trained face recognizer in one face recognizer open CV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, face-recognition

I am trying to train face recognizer but I don't want to train every time a new user data is entered in face database so I want to train new user data and then concatenate with previous trained recognizer. I have two trained recognizer I want to concatenate these two.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

This is my code I am reading from three recognizer and want to save them to one:

```
face_recognizer1=my.facerecognizer(cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()) 
face_recognizer1.read("trainer"+"/"+"s1"+".xml")
face_recognizer1.read("trainer"+"/"+"s2"+".xml")
face_recognizer1.read("trainer"+"/"+"s3"+".xml")
face_recognizer1.save("trainer"+"/"+"s11"+".xml")
```

Comment: What doesn't work with that code then? What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. Finish the tour and check your grammar (e.g. "three" or "the)!

Comment: it does not save the data of s1 s2 and s3 in s11 thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution, use update to update recognizer. more details at [opencv docs facerecognizer](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d65/classcv_1_1face_1_1FaceRecognizer.html#a8a4e73ea878dcd0c235d0487189d25f3)